# Better way to show/hide multiple divs?

Tags: jquery

I have 8 links that all need to show a div on click.  I want only 1 div to show at a time so when click on a new link the div that is currently displayed gets hidden and a new one gets displayed.  So far I have a jQuery solution that works but it's ugly.  Is there an easier/more correct way to accomplish what I want?

```
<div>
<a href="#" class="link">Click Link</a><br />
<a href="#" class="link2">Click Link 2</a><br />
<a href="#" class="link3">Click Link 3</a><br />
<a href="#" class="link4">Click Link 4</a><br />
<a href="#" class="link5">Click Link 5</a><br />
<a href="#" class="link6">Click Link 6</a><br />
<a href="#" class="link7">Click Link 7</a><br />
<a href="#" class="link8">Click Link 8</a><br />
 <div class="testVid hideDiv" style="background:pink; height:200px">Test Vid Div<br /><br /><span class="close">CLOSE</span></div>
<div class="testVid2  hideDiv" style="background:pink; height:200px">Test Vid Div 2<br /><br /><span class="close2">CLOSE 2</span></div>
<div class="testVid3 hideDiv" style="background:pink; height:200px">Test Vid Div 3<br /><br /><span class="close3">CLOSE 3</span></div>
<div class="testVid4  hideDiv" style="background:pink; height:200px">Test Vid Div 4<br /><br /><span class="close4">CLOSE 4</span></div>
<div class="testVid5 hideDiv" style="background:pink; height:200px">Test Vid Div 5<br /><br /><span class="close5">CLOSE 5</span></div>
<div class="testVid6 hideDiv" style="background:pink; height:200px">Test Vid Div 6<br /><br /><span class="close6">CLOSE 6</span></div>
<div class="testVid7 hideDiv" style="background:pink; height:200px">Test Vid Div 7<br /><br /><span class="close7">CLOSE 7</span></div>
<div class="testVid8 hideDiv" style="background:pink; height:200px">Test Vid Div 8<br /><br /><span class="close8">CLOSE 8</span></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.link").click(function(){
        $(".testVid").show();
        $(".testVid2").hide();
        $(".testVid3").hide();
        $(".testVid4").hide();
        $(".testVid5").hide();
        $(".testVid6").hide();
        $(".testVid7").hide();
        $(".testVid8").hide();
    });
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(".testVid").hide();
        });

    $("a.link2").click(function(){
        $(".testVid2").show();
        $(".testVid").hide();
        $(".testVid3").hide();
        $(".testVid4").hide();
        $(".testVid5").hide();
        $(".testVid6").hide();
        $(".testVid7").hide();
        $(".testVid8").hide();
    });
    $(".close2").click(function(){
        $(".testVid2").hide();
        });

    $("a.link3").click(function(){
        $(".testVid3").show();
        $(".testVid2").hide();
        $(".testVid").hide();
        $(".testVid4").hide();
        $(".testVid5").hide();
        $(".testVid6").hide();
        $(".testVid7").hide();
        $(".testVid8").hide();
    });
    $(".close3").click(function(){
        $(".testVid3").hide();
        });

    $("a.link4").click(function(){
        $(".testVid4").show();
        $(".testVid2").hide();
        $(".testVid3").hide();
        $(".testVid").hide();
        $(".testVid5").hide();
        $(".testVid6").hide();
        $(".testVid7").hide();
        $(".testVid8").hide();
    });
    $(".close4").click(function(){
        $(".testVid4").hide();
        });

    $("a.link5").click(function(){
        $(".testVid5").show();
        $(".testVid2").hide();
        $(".testVid3").hide();
        $(".testVid4").hide();
        $(".testVid").hide();
        $(".testVid6").hide();
        $(".testVid7").hide();
        $(".testVid8").hide();
    });
    $(".close5").click(function(){
        $(".testVid5").hide();
        })

    ;$("a.link6").click(function(){
        $(".testVid6").show();
        $(".testVid2").hide();
        $(".testVid3").hide();
        $(".testVid4").hide();
        $(".testVid5").hide();
        $(".testVid").hide();
        $(".testVid7").hide();
        $(".testVid8").hide();
    });
    $(".close6").click(function(){
        $(".testVid6").hide();
        });

    $("a.link7").click(function(){
        $(".testVid7").show();
        $(".testVid2").hide();
        $(".testVid3").hide();
        $(".testVid4").hide();
        $(".testVid5").hide();
        $(".testVid6").hide();
        $(".testVid").hide();
        $(".testVid8").hide();
    });
    $(".close7").click(function(){
        $(".testVid7").hide();
        });

    $("a.link8").click(function(){
        $(".testVid8").show();
        $(".testVid2").hide();
        $(".testVid3").hide();
        $(".testVid4").hide();
        $(".testVid5").hide();
        $(".testVid6").hide();
        $(".testVid7").hide();
        $(".testVid").hide();
    });
    $(".close8").click(function(){
        $(".testVid8").hide();
        });
    $(".hideDiv").css('display', 'none');
});
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/comatoseduck/sHjUG/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of jQuery selectors. I changed all your class attributes to ID attributes, and I appended a 1 to the ones without a number. Here's the Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/BLXWS/7/

Comment: Beautiful.  Would you mind explaining to me what `a[id^="link"]` and  `var vid_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("link", "#testVid");` mean so I can have a better understanding?

Comment: Ofcourse. `a[id^="link"]` is a jQuery selector, it basically filters out all `a` tags that have ID attributes starting with `link`. In the next line, I get the ID attribute of the link click, lets say `link2`, to convert that ID to the corresponding testVid, i just replace the link with `#testVid`, so now it becomes `#testVid2` and I can just hide/show it accordingly. I like to use the ID attribute when working with selectors, because often times you will want to use more than just one class.

Answer (score 3):

Each div should have a class and an id.  The class should be used to group the types of divs you have. The id should be unique to each div.

So, if you have some divs that contain photos of cars and some that contain photos of squirrels, you should have two classes of divs

```
<div class="PhotosCars" id="Car1"></div>
<div class="PhotosCars" id="Car2"></div>
<div class="PhotosCars" id="Car3"></div>
<div class="PhotosSquirrels" id="Squirrels1"></div>
<div class="PhotosSquirrels" id="Squirrels2"></div>
<div class="PhotosSquirrels" id="Squirrels3"></div>

// hide squirrels
$(".PhotosSquirrels").hide();

// hide cars
$(".PhotosCars").hide();

// show single photo
$("#Car3").show();
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was just about to type up *an example* of the right answer (which was what this question was missing).  Now I can just go to work and earn money to feed my family.

Comment: If I have the right answer and helped you, please check the box.  jQuery is awesome. Check out the new QR Code Generator on my web site, under jQuery examples.  http://www.evikjames.com/

Comment: what if I don't have different types of divs?

Answer (score 1):

- assign all items a common class
- attach a click handler to all at once `$(".commonClass").click(..)`
- in the function hide all (with the same selector) and show only the current `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLXWS/14/) with common classes for links and divs, and changed numberd ones with ids (since they were unique anyway). With that you can do:

```
$(".showlink").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".testVid").hide()
  $("#vid"+$(this).attr("id").replace("link","")).show();    
});
```

Comment: the solution you provided and the updated fiddle doesn't work

Comment: Sorry. Forgot about `preventDefault()`. Edited and updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without changing anything in your html:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $('div[class^="testVid"]').hide();
    $('div[class="testVid'+ $(this).attr('class').replace(/link/, '') +'"]').show();
});

$('span[class^="close"]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

I suggest you take a batter look at [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), those can save your life.

Comment: Too bad I can't accept 2 answers.  I'm definitely going to brush up on selectors!

Answer (score 0):

**Make an use of attributes/values that elements you want to connect/handle have in common.**

In your case what your links and divs relates together is the part of their class name (link number and the div number; they are hidden inside `a` and `div` class name `link1 --> testVid1`).

That is also what your links relates together (in this case you focus on the first part of their class name). So you don't need click function for every one of them but just one:

```
// this selector selects all a tags of which class attribute contains value of "link"
$('a[class*="link"]')
```

Same goes for spans that close your divs:

```
$('span[class*="close"]')
```

So your javascript/jquery code (no need to change html code) looks something like this:

```
   $(function() {
    $('a[class*="link"]').click(function(e){
       // prevent default behaviour of anchor tag
       e.preventDefault();
       //reset current selection (hide all divs)
       $('div[class*="testVid"]').hide();
       // get clicked anchor tag number
       $this = ($(this).attr("class")).replace("link", "testVid");
       // find and display div that is related to clicked a element
       $('.'+$this).show();
     });

     $('span[class*="close"]').click(function(e){
       // prevent default behaviour of anchor element
       e.preventDefault();
       //get parent element of clicked anchor element and hide it
       $(this).parent('div').hide();
     });

    });
```

Exactly in cases like yours jQuery is very helpful especially [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).