# jQuery show/hide multiple divs

Tags: jquery, dom, show-hide

Please help me in showing/hiding multiple divs in jQuery. I have a PHP code that produce multiple tabs and multiple boxes, with ids that nearly identical. Here is the produced HTML lines:

```
<ul id="tab-country">
    <li><a id="africa" rel="1" href="#">africa</a></li>
    <li><a id="europe" rel="1" href="#">europe</a></li>
    <li><a id="asia" rel="1" href="#">asia</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="country-glass-1-africa" style="display:none;">Africa Glass 1</div>
<div id="country-glass-1-europe" style="display:none;">Europe Glass 1</div>
<div id="country-glass-1-asia" style="display:none;">Asia Glass 1</div>

<div id="country-spoon-1-africa" style="display:none;">Africa Spoon 1</div>
<div id="country-spoon-1-europe" style="display:none;">Europe Spoon 1</div>
<div id="country-spoon-1-asia" style="display:none;">Asia Spoon 1</div>

<ul id="tab-country">
    <li><a id="africa" rel="2" href="#">africa</a></li>
    <li><a id="europe" rel="2" href="#">europe</a></li>
    <li><a id="asia" rel="2" href="#">asia</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="country-glass-2-africa" style="display:none;">Africa Glass 2</div>
<div id="country-glass-2-europe" style="display:none;">Europe Glass 2</div>
<div id="country-glass-2-asia" style="display:none;">Asia Glass 2</div>

<div id="country-spoon-2-africa" style="display:none;">Africa Spoon 2</div>
<div id="country-spoon-2-europe" style="display:none;">Europe Spoon 2</div>
<div id="country-spoon-2-asia" style="display:none;">Asia Spoon 2</div>
```

And at the end of the page, here is the jQuery lines:

```
$(function(){
    $("[id$='-africa']").toggle();
    $("#tab-country li a").click(function(event){
        var country = $(this).attr('id');
        var itemid = $(this).attr('rel');
        /* the following 2 lines are not working - i want to hide them if they're shown */
        $("[id^='country-glass-']"+itemid+"-").css('display','block').toggle();
        $("[id^='country-spoon-']"+itemid+"-").css('display','block').toggle();
        /* the following works as it is supposed to be */
        $("#country-glass-"+itemid+"-"+country).toggle();
        $("#country-spoon-"+itemid+"-"+country).toggle();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Please help me in hiding the shown divs, when one of the tab-country item is clicked.
Anyway, thank you for your attention.

Comment: Very similar question: [Better way to show/hide multiple divs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861905/better-way-to-show-hide-multiple-divs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your 2 lines aren't working is because you have itemid outside your `[id=<>]` selector.
You can also do something like this: `$('selector:visible').hide();` to only hide visible content, rather than setting display to block and then toggle.

```
$('[id^="country-glass-'+itemid+'-"], [id^="country-spoon-'+itemid+'-"]').filter(':visible').hide();
```

Comment: It works! Much obliged. I hope you can help many more members like you did. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the itemid inside the [], like 
`$("[id^='country-glass-' + itemid + '-']").css...`

Comment: Although it is not exactly what i want, i really appreciate your attention. Cheers, Rodolfo.